# Inserting into a table with a serial column using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have two simple tables in PostgreSQL that I created through pgAdmin4:

Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1
(
    id serial,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table2
(
    fk_id integer,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (name),
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_id)
        REFERENCES public.table1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

After creating this second table with a foreign key referencing the first table the data type id from table1 changes to integer automatically:

[image]

And if I try to change manually the type to serial it isn't found.

And also using psycopg2 this insert works:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "user",
                              password = "pass",
                              host = "localhost",
                              port = "5432",
                              database = "db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
record_to_insert = (1,'sometext')
cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)

connection.commit()
```

But this one fails:

```
postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES (%s)"""
record_to_insert = ('sometext')
```

Printing this error: "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL Read the section about serial types. TL;DR serial is not a real type, just a shorthand way of defining an integer column with a sequence.

Comment: You expect what to increment? If you defined the table with only one column, inserting anything will be only into that `id` column, which means it won't use the sequence, so nothing will increment.

Comment: But I expected it to autoincrement when I insert a new value: "INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('somtext')" <- This fails. And this works -> "INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,"sometext")"

Comment: I made simple tables for this question. Real tables have more columns

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Error? Doesn't increment?

Comment: The `serial` simply defines a default value take from a sequence. It **will** increment properly - but you should [use an identity column](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) with modern Postgres versions.

Comment: By "fails" I mean it doesn't insert anything (I edited the question). And about identety column I read that it is not supported by pgAdmin4 but defining the column as serial should still work

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Postgres, because the plain SQL works: https://rextester.com/FBVW93753

Comment: The insert failed because you didn't create a tuple.  Try `record_to_insert = ('sometext',)`

Comment: You are right @Jeremy I needed that comma, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed a comma as commented @Jeremy

```
record_to_insert = ('sometext',)
```